# Как правильно написать: "выращенных" или "выращенного"

Tags: согласование

*Прекрасное сицилийское вино глубокого темно-красного цвета из смеси красных сортов винограда урожая 2017 года, выращенных/выращенного на лучших землях Сицилии в регионе Terre Siciliane.*

Comment: Конечно, виноград выращен, а не сорта. Надо только чуть-чуть задуматься.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно "выращенн**ого**": для производства вина *выращивают* **виноград** разных сортов, а не "сорта винограда". Новые сорта винограда выводят (или получают) тоже путём *выращивания винограда*. "Вино из смеси сортов винограда" (вместо более строгого "из смеси винограда разных сортов") - условность, которая позволяет разгрузить предложение с большим количеством уточнений при "винограде".